# c# Insert item in nested list of objects

Tags: c#, list, linq, lambda, nested

I have class like this :

```
public class Abc
{   
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Abc> Child{ get; set; }
}
```

I have a nested list of **Abc** like this with two parent items with their children :

```
Abc (Id = 1)
|
|-- Abc (Id = 2)
|-- Abc (Id = 3)
     |
     |-- Abc (Id = 4)
          |
          |-- Abc (Id =5)
Abc (Id = 6)
|
|-- Abc (Id = 7)
|-- Abc (Id = 8)
     |
     |-- Abc (Id = 9)
          |
          |-- (Id = 10)
```

**==== UPDATE ====**

Now that being said, I have two input parameter:

1. Id = 4
2. An object of class Abc (Id = 9)
3. An object of class Abc (Id = 11)

I need to find out the object with id 4 in entire list and insert the object in its child only if that object does not exist in the list.

So id = 9 already exists , so I cannot insert. But I can insert the object with Id = 11.

**=== UPDATE 2 ====** 
So after id = 11 is added, the list should look like this.

```
Abc (Id = 1)
|
|-- Abc (Id = 2)
|-- Abc (Id = 3)
     |
     |-- Abc (Id = 4)
          |
          |-- Abc (Id =5)
          |-- Abc (Id = 11) -- ADDED
Abc (Id = 6)
|
|-- Abc (Id = 7)
|-- Abc (Id = 8)
     |
     |-- Abc (Id = 9)
          |
          |-- (Id = 10)
```

I do not know how to achieve this. 
Can anyone please help with this ? It can be c# lambda or linq or any other method.

Comment: Is this something you do a lot or will it only ever be once? If you do it once then just recursing through your lists is probably the way to go. If you do it a lot then you might want to store a dictionary of your ABC with their id as key so you can find a specific ABC very quickly when you have its id.

Comment: If you can show us your attempt and point at the problems you face, it'll be a lot easier for us to help you.

Comment: Hi Guys, I have just updated the requirement. Please see the section under UPDATE. Sorry for missing it out.

Comment: Any help on this ? The id should be searched on entire list always.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, it's up to you to check where the Child property is not null.

```
public class Abc
{
    public Abc(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }

    public int Id { get; }
    public List<Abc> Child { get; set; }

    public Abc FindById(int id)
    {
        if (Id == id) return this;
        if (Child == null) return null;

        foreach (var childItem in Child)
        {
            var result = childItem.FindById(id);
            if (result != null) return result;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public bool HasChild(int id)
    {
      return FindById(id) != null;
    }

    public Abc AddChildIfNotExist(Abc child)
    {
        if (child == null) return this;
        if (!HasChild(child.Id))Child.Add(child);
        return this;
    }
}

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var a = new Abc(1)
        {
            Child = new List<Abc>
            {
                new Abc(2),
                new Abc(3)
                {
                    Child = new List<Abc>
                    {
                        new Abc(7)
                        {
                            Child = new List<Abc>
                            {
                                new Abc(5)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Abc(6)
                {
                    Child = new List<Abc>
                    {
                        new Abc(8)
                        {
                            Child = new List<Abc>
                            {
                                new Abc(9),
                                new Abc(4)
                                {
                                   Child = new List<Abc>()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        a
            .FindById(4)
            .AddChildIfNotExist(new Abc(10))
            .AddChildIfNotExist(new Abc(4));
    }
```

Comment: +1 for working implementation. But according to OP's nested list,  `Abc Id = 6` is not a child of `Abc Id = 1`.

Comment: Let me try that.

Comment: I tried this, it inserts the child in id 4 but only returns that list not the entire. The changes should be made to the entire list.

Comment: What do you mean by "the changes should be made to the entire list" ?
The child should be added to all nested lists ?

Comment: Hi, I have4 dited the question. Please take a look at UPDATE 2 .

Comment: a.FindById(4) returns the Child with Id 4.
If you want the root object, just use the variable a...

Comment: Hi, I have tried what you said, it is kind a sort of, but if the new child is Abc (Id = 1), it is adding that under Abc (Id = 4), but it should not as it already exists.

Comment: Any help on this ? The id should be searched on entire list always.

Answer (score 0):

Try recursion, should work just fine. At every member check its ID. If it's the ID you want, just insert the object into its child. If it is not, check if it has children. If it doesn't, go to the next element. If it does, check its children in the same way as you checked the current member (this is where recursion comes in).

For the sake of practicing, you could write the code yourself. Feel free to ask if it doesn't work.

Comment: Ok let me try, but I am not sure how do I get to [Abc (Id = 6)], once I complete Abc (Id = 1), as there are no links between them.

Comment: @Sandipan. You will have to do a Foreach("Elements in the main list")

Comment: What you have at every level is a list. So at the outer level you have a list that is made of two objects: abc id=1 and abc id=6. Inside every abc object (if it has children) you will have the same looking list consisting of X number of abc members. So you always have to loop that list as @Maxter said. You either call the function again if there are children, or you just return some value (lets say `false`) if it is not found on the most inner level.

Comment: @Sandipan regarding your edit: list is passed by reference. So really, when you find the ID you need, just add to its list of children the object you want to add. The list you passed will automatically update. If you want to know if that object already exists before inserting, you could also have two separate functions (which looks for elements the same way, but performs different actions), one of which checks if the object exists and the other inserts. Then you check if it exists, if not, try to insert.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should work:

```
public void findIndex(Abc myClass)
{
    if(myClass.Id == 4)
    {
        //Insert the new item here in the children childs
    }
    else
    {
        Foreach(Abc children in myClass.Child)
        {
            findIndex(children)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This would not check the root level `Abc` object.